# Проблема с форматированием даты при помощи Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, carbon

Есть дата в формате 'день.месяц.год' иди 'd.m.Y' поступающая на сервер в виде строки. Дата передается в качестве параметра адресной строки.

В контроллере, мне нужно привести ее к формату 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

Для этого я использую следующий метод Carbon:
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $startDate  )->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

На выходе получаю дату:
$date = "2017-05-01 17:40:26";

Все бы ничего но изначально в форматируемой строке, небыло указанно времени. Carbon вставил его автоматически. Причем время судя по всему вставляется текущее.

Я хочу что бы на выходе из метода было:
$date = "2017-05-01 **00:00:00**"; в не "2017-05-01 **17:40:26**";

Что нужно сделать что бы время рядом с датой было **00:00:00**.

Comment: А есди в самом формате указать `...createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', ...`?

Comment: @Bookin при запросе выкидывает ошибку "InvalidArgumentException". Видно хочет что бы в форматируемой базовой строке было указано время хоть какое то "00:00:00"

Comment: Честно говоря в первые вижу этот класс))

Comment: `Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($startDate))`

Comment: @Bookin Нуу это часть экосистемы Laravel =). Не очень страшный класс

Comment: Ну он как бы не пугает, судя по всему сахарок к DateTime(), просто написал к тому что на угад даю варианты)

Comment: @Bookin Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($startDate)) совет помог.

Comment: На всякий случай, может быть кому то это пригодиться. Видео о том как поменять timozone в Laravel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lcR7Z1c8zU , а также список поддерживаемых тайм зон: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php . Мне как раз это нужно было, прицепом к заданному вопросу.

Comment: А что мешает сделать так: `$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $startDate )->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00)');` ?

Comment: А почему нельзя? Вы указываете нужные модификаторы, а ненужные не указываете.